# Get total number of same objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
route: [
  {
    flyFrom: "CDG",
    flyTo: "DUB",
    return: 0,
  },
  {
    flyFrom: "DUB",
    flyTo: "SXF",
    return: 0,
  },
  {
    flyFrom: "SFX",
    flyTo: "CDG",
    return: 1,
  }
]
```

I need to count how many times there is return: 0 and how many times there is return: 1.

The end result would look like:

for the cases where return: 0 appears 2 times --- 1 Stop

for the cases where return: 1 appears 1 time --- Non-stop

Comment: do you have some code to show?

Comment: Tried this but doesn`t work: 'var stops_count = route.length;
                $.each(function(route.length) { stops_count[route.length] = (stops_count[route.length] || 0)+1; });'

Comment: `return` is a reserved word (also a keyword) in javascript and thus cannot be used as an object's key.

Comment: @ThomasShields Reserved words and keywords are allowed as object's keys in Javascript.

Comment: @Paulpro whoops, forgot that was fixed in ES5! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can filter `0` and `1` values with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check the length of result (ES6 syntax):

```
var route = [
    { flyFrom: 'CDG', flyTo: 'DUB', return : 0, },
    { flyFrom: 'DUB', flyTo: 'SXF', return : 0, },
    { flyFrom: 'SFX', flyTo: 'CDG', return : 1, }
];

var zeros = route.filter(r => r.return === 0).length;
var ones = route.filter(r => r.return === 1).length;
```

ES5 analogy:

```
var zeros = route.filter(function(r) {
    return r.return === 0;
}).length;
```

Another solution would be to reduce array:

```
var zeros = route.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.return === 0), 0);
```

Comment: Is the same solution without arrows and adding `function` and return

Comment: I wonder when the community accept solutions without ES5 alternatives

Comment: *filter* seems inefficient as it creates a new array just to count the length. Consider *reduce* instead.

Comment: @RobG thanks for pointing that out. I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over and count the returns in an object with a single loop.

```js
var data = { route: [{ flyFrom: "CDG", flyTo: "DUB", 'return': 0, }, { flyFrom: "DUB", flyTo: "SXF", 'return': 0, }, { flyFrom: "SFX", flyTo: "CDG", 'return': 1 }] },
    count = {};

data.route.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.return] = (count[a.return] || 0) + 1;
});

Object.keys(count).forEach(function (k) {
    document.getElementById('id' + k).innerHTML = count[k];
});
```

```html
<p>for the cases where return: 0 appears <span id="id0">0</span> times --- 1 Stop</p>
<p>for the cases where return: 1 appears <span id="id1">0</span> time --- Non-stop</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick ES 5 solution:

```
var zeros = 0, ones = 0;

route.forEach(function(entry) {
    if(entry.return == 0) zeros++;
    else if(entry.return == 1) ones++;
});

alert("Zeros: " + zeros + " | Ones: " + ones);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a json object. then select what child you want. for example:

```
var jsonObject = data {
route: [
{
flyFrom: "CDG",
flyTo: "DUB",
return: 0,
},
{
flyFrom: "DUB",
flyTo: "SXF",
return: 0,
},
{
flyFrom: "SFX",
flyTo: "CDG",
return: 1,
}]
}

var zeroCount = 0;
var oneCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.route.length; i++){
var j = jsonObject.route[i].return;
if(j == 0) zeroCount++;
else oneCount++;
}
```

Comment: What is a "json object"?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return an object with two keys, `outbound` and `inbound`, containing the required messages, e.g. "non-stop", "1 stop", etc.:

```
function countStops(route) { 
   const legs = route.reduce((result, r) => {
        const leg = r['return'] ? 'inbound' : 'outbound';
        result[leg]++;
        return result;
    }, { outbound: 0, inbound: 0 });

    const message = parts => {
        switch (parts) {
            case 1:
                return 'non-stop';
            case 2:
                return '1 stop';
            default:
                return `${parts - 1} stops`;
        }
    };

    return {
        outbound: message(legs.outbound),
        inbound: message(legs.inbound)
    };
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iaretiga/njx0nsyh/) here.